# Code compiles with javac but not Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, java-stream

This code compiles without issues with `javac`, but in Eclipse it gives the following error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Object> to Set<String>`

What could the issue be? javac is version `1.8.0_101` and Eclipse is using `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test
{
    public class Foo {
        public List<Bar> bars;
    }

    public class Bar {
        public String baz;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> list = null;

        Set<String> set = list.stream()
                .flatMap(x -> x.bars.stream().map(y -> y.baz))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get in Eclipse console ?

Comment: Works fine in my Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) using jdk1.8.0_91.

Comment: Also works fine on Eclipse Neon.3. What version of Eclipse are you using? If it is Luna you need to move to a newer version.

Comment: Probably this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453422 . I advice moving to the latest version of Eclipse.